# Is this function onto?

Tags: functions, connectedness

This is from exercise 5.2.6 in "How to Prove It" by David Velleman.

Let $A=\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{R})$. Define $f:\mathbb{R}\to A$ by the formula $f(x)=\{y\in\mathbb{R}|y^2<x\}$.

The following website claims that it is, in fact, onto: http://www.inchmeal.io/htpi/ch-5/sec-5.2.html. However, as I understand it, $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{R})$ also includes the subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that aren't connected, such as $(-1,0)\cup(\pi,4)$, which wouldn't be in the range of $f$ since the elements of $Ran(f)$ appear to be connected intervals.

Answer (score 1):

If $x \le 0$, then $f(x)= \emptyset$ and if $x>0$, then $f(x)=(- \sqrt{x},\sqrt{x})$. Hence $f$ is not onto.

Answer (score 0):

Fred's answer is great, but also you can use Cantor's theorem.

Define $g:\mathbb{R}^+\rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ to be $g(x)=f(x)$, since for $x\leq 0$ you have $f(x)=f(0)=\emptyset$ we have that the image of $g$ and $f$ are the same (for me $0\in\mathbb{R}^+$). Now $g$ is on to one, applying Cantor's theorem which says that there is no one to one and onto map from a set to it's power set it follows that $g$ is not onto and therefore so is $f$.